# PostgreSQL Immutable function usage

Tags: postgresql, immutability

I'm trying to fasten posgresql selection using a function by means of saying it's immutable or stable, so I have a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data(uid uuid)
RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'UUID %', $1;
-- DO SOME STUFF
    RETURN 0;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

When I call it like:

```
SELECT get_data('3642e529-b098-4db4-b7e7-6bb62f8dcbba'::uuid)
  FROM table
 WHERE true LIMIT 100;
```

I have 100 results and only one notice raised

When I call it this way:

```
SELECT get_data(table.hash)
  FROM table
 WHERE 1 = 1 AND table.hash = '3642e529-b098-4db4-b7e7-6bb62f8dcbba' LIMIT 100;
```

I have 100 result and 100 notices raised

*the condition (table.hash = '3642e529-b098-4db4-b7e7-6bb62f8dcbba') added to make sure that the in param is the same*

*table.hash is uuid type*

The questions is:
**So how can force PG to some how cache the result of the function?** ( if it's possibe )
I want to have only one notice ( function call ) be raised in the second case...

Comment: Why are you trying to pipe output via `RAISE NOTICE`? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example `get_data('3642e529-b098-4db4-b7e7-6bb62f8dcbba'::uuid)` is a constant, independent of table rows, so it is evaluated *once*.

In the second example `get_data(table.hash)` is functionally depending on a column value, therefore it is evaluated *once per row*.

If you want to evaluate the function once, it cannot depend on a value from a column (when more than one row is processed).

---

After discussion in comments, here is an example how to call function only once per hash:

```
SELECT *, get_data(x.hash) AS some_data_once_per_hash
FROM    (
    SELECT hash, count(*) AS ct
    FROM   table
    WHERE  table.hash = '3642e529-b098-4db4-b7e7-6bb62f8dcbba'
    GROUP  BY 1
    ) x
```

Comment: So there is no way to make PG to cache the result?

Comment: @Good.Dima: Well, your first example would be the way, although it's not "caching" per se.

Comment: @Good.Dima - Why do you want to dump out the same string 100 times?

Comment: @JackManey I need to aggregate diff uids, and I want to call function once per uid...

Comment: @Good.Dima - Well, why not create an aggregate function, then?

Comment: @Good.Dima: You can call the function *after* the aggregation. Aggregate in a subquery or CTE and call the function on the next query level.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - What do you mean?

Comment: @Good.Dima - Do whatever aggregation you need to do, **then** call the function.

Comment: @Good.Dima: I added an example to my answer to demonstrate what I (we) mean.

Comment: I see, this is a simple variant of the query, in the original version I do not call the function for every row ( there is and IF ) and I need to sort the total result with the limit and offset.

Comment: Good. But you can't use `like` with a `uuid` type

Comment: No grouping possible in my case(((

Comment: @Good.Dima: I suppose you start a new question where you post your *complete* query.

Answer (score 0):

If Erwin's answer is not good for your case you can either create a [materialized view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) or a [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/trigger-definition.html) to update a *"computed column"*